# Select all IDs from x table that are not in column_foo of y table

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I select all IDs from table_x that are not present in any row of table y in column_foo ?

I'm struggling to do this with a single SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to avoid subqueries if you can. An `INNER JOIN` will return only rows that meet the join criteria.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    x.id
FROM
    table_x x
    INNER JOIN table_y y ON (x.id = y.id_column_in_y)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id FROM x
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM y WHERE foo = id)
```

Or

```
SELECT id FROM x
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT foo FROM y)
```

Or if `y.foo` is not a nullable column, you can even do:

```
SELECT x.id FROM x
  LEFT JOIN y ON x.id = y.foo
  WHERE y.foo IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do something like:

```
SELECT id FROM table_x WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT column_foo FROM table_y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use a LEFT JOIN.  More explanation and examples here.

[Visual Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)